# How to close SlidingMenu Very slowly

Tags: android, android-animation, slidingmenu

I used jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu in my code.
When I touch the menu button, Menu will be showed and closed. 
Also I want to close menu very slowly. So I tried overridePendingTransition, But it does not work ! How to handle this?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu men) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    if (menu.isMenuShowing())
        menu.showContent();
    else{
        menu.showMenu(); overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out); }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea except for overriding showMenu or adding your custom method in SlidingMenu

Answer (score 0):

this is my fadein.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"          
        android:duration="500"
    android:repeatCount="0" />
 </set>
```

just change the duration parameter will do, for fadeout just swap the toAlpha and fromAlpha, hope this helps